# Can I load "powered by Google" logo from Google's server?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, policies

I'm using Google Places API to display POIs on a website. According to Google's policy, I'm showing the "powered by Google" logo on the page. But it's not clear whether I'm allowed to load the logo directly from Google's server or I must serve it from my own server!

On https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies they are providing the zip containing the logo. But I'm loading the logo directly from developers.google.com:

```
<img src="https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/images/powered-by-google-on-white.png">
```

Is it (legally) allowed to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not coding

Comment: @geocodezip : thanks for your concern. I gave it a second thought before posting it here. Do you think https://law.stackexchange.com/ is the appropriate place to post this question? (I think no). I agree, it's about legal issues, but that's related to coding as well. Coding is all about real life issues, not just for loops.. ;-)

Comment: It is an appropriate place to post such a question, and you may even be likely to find someone who knows the answer to your question first hand.

Comment: from meta: [How do we handle ethical/legal questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280151/how-do-we-handle-ethical-legal-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Never experienced such thing, just sharing my idea on that.
I can't see any such thing in policy regarding weather you need to load from own server or using public google URI.
But there might be one potential risk when using direct google public url, in case of google change that resource path, your site gonna be broken and it wont show the image any more. so for better control, you should use your own server I guess.